# How to purchase and bitcoin marketing question still around

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

[This question has been on SO for five days.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727658/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-buy-ether) I marked it for closing and flagged one of the answers. In my view, it's off topic because it's asking:

1. How do I purchase a product?
2. Market rates and exchanges for bitcoin

How has this managed to hang around or am I totally misinterpreting it?

Comment: Yeah, that question is blatantly off-topic.

Comment: *"How has this managed to hang around"* - I doubt its one tag gets too much traffic, and the close vote queue is pretty long.

Comment: And... It's gone.

Comment: .. but please don't take this as an incentive to post here for every question that ought to have been closed! There is a chat room just for that (cannot recall its address tho'.)

Comment: @Jongware you're not referring to the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room, are you?

Comment: @rene: that's the one, yes.